KeyError when renaming int-type column names with an object dictionary
So I am trying to rename the unemply_states.columns to the names in the dictionary (id_to_state), but I keep getting the error shown. I don't know if this is a factor but the two have different data types.
The code with the error is:
[id_to_state[c] for c in unemply_states.columns]

The error is:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[123], line 1
----> 1 [id_to_state[c] for c in unemply_states.columns]

KeyError: 0

I have tried changing the data type of the columns to object to match the dictionary but the error persists.
The code to change the columns which are integers to object is:
def convert_int_column_names_to_str(unemply_states):
    # Convert integer column names to strings
    unemply_states.columns = unemply_states.columns.map(str)
    return unemply_states

Which still returns the value as integers as opposed to object.

Either use get to handle missing keys:
unemply_states.columns = [id_to_state.get(c, c) for c in unemply_states.columns]

or better rename:
unemply_states = unemply_states.rename(columns=id_to_state)


Let me do that, i'll tell you how that goes

So, the code has no error but the column names do not change still

How do you check this? Can you provide a reproducible example of your DataFrame's columns and the dictionary? edit your question to add the outputs of unemply_states.columns and id_to_state
